# Excel throws exception HRESULT: 0x800A03EC whilst user is still typing in a cell and cell values change

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm creating an Excel addin in C# and I change some cell values with the addin button click. It works smoothly, however, I've noticed that if a user is trying to type something in ANY cell (not only the ones I'm changing values to), it will always throw `HRESULT: 0x800A03EC` exception.

My code is simple, for example I've tested this with only this piece of code:

```
private void buttonFoo_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    var ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
    ws.Range["A1"].Value = "bar";
}
```

And when I click on a random cell, type "foo", BUT I do not click anywhere on the worksheet, I do not finish writting "foo", instead I click on the buttonFoo whilst I'm still focused in my cell and it throws this exception.

This picture can explains what I'm trying to do, I'll be clicking on the Test button in the picture whilst still typing like this:

[image]

I thought this exception was happening if I was trying to type something in a specific cell and that specific cell I am also changing in my code. But that is not the case. I've tried selecting a cell that is not used, like this:

```
ws.Range["B1"].Select();
```

Does not help. I've tried sending ESC key to cancel the user typing:

```
excelApp.SendKeys("{ESCAPE}");
```

I tested this and it will actually send Escape, but it will still throw an exception. I'm completely out of ideas and have not found anything regarding this issue. I mean I could possibly surround everything with try/catch looking for this exception, but that's just terrible.. Anyone got an idea what to do?

Comment: Because the application is in edit mode, most code won't run until you finish editing a cell. Try checking the `.Interactive` property of the application first.

Comment: I've just tried changing the `.Interactive`, but it still throws an exception when I try it.. maybe it just isnt possible to run code whilst application is in edit mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this instead to see if the application is busy:

```
bool XLAppBusy()
{
    if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive == false)
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive = false;
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}

private void buttonFoo_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    if (XLAppBusy() == false)
    {       
        ws.Range["A1"].Value = "bar";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well damn, that's an interesting approach that works.. cheers